# Problem running 'cargo build --release ' on substrate-node-template for M1

Tags: substrate-node-template, build, macos

I was trying to run substrate following the installation process on the docs and I have a mac running with M1.

I followed the instructions to the letter, installing Rosseta 2 and cmake and also I tried every workaround for M1 that i could found but the error still persist.

Not sure if I'm missing something or if i need to use an older version of something for it to work...

[image: error]

[image: error 2]

This is my first time trying to run a substrate node and also my first time posting in here so i really hope i'm using the format correctly.

Thank you very much in advance!

UPDATE. Adding `rustup show` and `rustup +nightly show` outputs

[image: rustup show]

[image: rustup +nightly show]

Comment: Please include the output of `rustup show` and `rustup +nightly show` in your post.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything fancy anymore regarding installing for M1. I would clean up all the various rust installs you have, and start from scratch, simply following these instructions: https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos/

Comment: I updated my question to include the updates for the 'show' commands...
And i already uninstalled an reinstalled everything following the instructions for the second time, I'm not sure what could be the problem...
Thank you very much for your responses!!

Comment: Try using the toolchain that is listed in the [docs](https://docs.substrate.io/install/macos/#install-required-packages-and-rust) Shawn referenced: `stable-aarch64-apple-darwin` and `nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin`.